# Handling exception (when no connection) in pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pyodbc

I'm trying to catch the exception when connecting to database and have no connection, but I always freeze at pyodbc.connect(connstr). I tried all errors from [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Errors), tried just "except Exception" but I see my program just freeze when cannot connect to database and don't check except section. (Freeze is caused by my on-purpose disconnection from database and program just does nothing (windows "no answer") until my hard reset):

```
    import pyodbc
    connstr=('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server="server_ip";port=1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Database="name";uid="uid";pwd="pwd";')
    try:
        print("I'm here - no problem")
        conn=pyodbc.connect(connstr)
        print("of course not here")
    except ...no_matter_what_I_write_here... :
        print("but never there too")
```

Comment: is the freeze caused by a long timeout? Please show the output...

Comment: There is no output, no errors, nothing

Comment: ok, then check the documentation of `pyodbc.connect` to see what the behaviour is in case of error and if there are any parameters/global cfg you can set to change the timeout limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was too simple (thank You Pynchia for Your suggestion):

```
try:
    conn=pyodbc.connect(connstr, timeout=5)
except pyodbc.Error as err:
    print("Couldn't connect")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not connecting on thread. Coz Signals will not work in non main thread.

```
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager

 class TimeoutError(Exception): pass

 @contextmanager
 def time_limit(seconds):
     def signal_handler(signum, frame):
         raise TimeoutError("Time out")
     signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
     signal.alarm(seconds)
     try:
          yield
     finally:
          signal.alarm(0)


 try:
     with time_limit(10):
          conn=pyodbc.connect(connstr)     
 except TimeoutError as e:
        print "couldn't connect for long time"
```